# Why svg elements created from JavaScript are not visible?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

Here is how I try to create circles:

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/";
var circle = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.element = document.createElementNS(
      svgns, "circle"
    );
    this.element.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", x);
    this.element.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", y);
    this.element.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  CIRCLE_RADIUS);
    this.element.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", randomColor());
    svg.appendChild(this.element);
}
circle(100, 100);
```

Only circle that was hardcoded there initially is displayed. Two another, 
which are added by my script are not visible, but they are almost identica, as seed in DevTools:

[image: They are clearly in the DOM, as seen on screenshot]

Here is link to [CodePen](http://codepen.io/bunyk-1472854887/pen/XMpbxp?editors=1010). Maybe I messed up some namespaces or styles or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You messed up the namespace. You want

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
```

No / at the end compared to yours.

```js
var CIRCLE_RADIUS = 10;
var svg = document.getElementById('canvas');

var randomColor = function() {
  return ['red', 'green', 'blue'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var circle = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.element = document.createElementNS(
      svgns, "circle"
    );
    this.element.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", x);
    this.element.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", y);
    this.element.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  CIRCLE_RADIUS);
    this.element.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", randomColor());
    svg.appendChild(this.element);
}
circle(100, 100);
circle(10, 10)
```

```html
<svg width="800" height="800" id="canvas">
    <circle cx="60" cy="10" r="10" fill="gray"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: For those who don't see the difference --> `/` at the end is removed